# MTurk how to upload file to S3 when task is submitted

Tags: javascript, amazon-s3, mechanicalturk, mturk

I am trying to create a task on Amazon MTurk, where the workers would collect some data and upload a single file when they are ready & submit the task. When the task is submitted, I want to upload the file to my linked S3 bucket - which is mostly based on [this tutorial](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-how-to-create-hits-that-ask-workers-to-upload-files-using-amazon-cognito-and-amazon-s3-38acb1108633).

However, the file is sometimes uploaded successfully, and sometimes not. Since the `S3.upload` function is asynchronous, it looks like the task submission is sometimes completed before the file upload is completed. I am a `javascript` newbie: I tried to make this happen synchronously, but it still doesn't work properly. Here is my `javascript` code:

```
<script>
    let config = {
        region: 'xxx',
        pool: 'xxx',
        bucket: 'xxx'
    }
    
    AWS.config.region = config.region;
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: config.pool,
    });
    
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        params: {Bucket: config.bucket},
    });
  
    start_upload = function (event) {
        $("#status").text("Uploading...");
    
        let file = $("#file").prop('files')[0];
        if (file === null || file === undefined) {
            alert("You must upload a file before submitting.");
            $("#status").text("");
            return false;
        }
    
        console.log('Filename: ' + file.name);
    
        let workerId = turkGetParam('workerId');
        let fileKey = '${food_name}' + '/' + workerId + '-' + file.name;
    
        return upload_to_s3(file, fileKey);
    };
  
    upload_to_s3 = async (file, fileKey) => {
        const params = {
            Key: fileKey,
            Body: file,
            ContentType: file.type,
            ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
        };
    
        try {
            console.log("Starting upload...");
            const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
            console.log("Done uploading file");
            $("#status").text("Success.");
            return true;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading data. ", err);
            alert("Failed to upload, please try again. If the problem persists, contact the Requester.");
            $("#status").text("");
            return false;
        }
    }
  
    // Validate and upload file on submit
    window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'return start_upload()'); }
</script>
```

Here is the relevant part of the layout of this task (HIT):
[image]

How can I make sure that the file upload is completed before the task is completed? I saw that I can overwrite the default submit button added by MTurk, but I would prefer not doing that if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem: `S3#upload` returns a `ManagedUpload` object, but it doesn't mean that the file upload is completed. I am now using promises and in the callback I submit the form manually. Note that the form is provided by MTurk by default. I just find it by its ID and invoke the `submit` function manually.

For reference, here is the working code:

```
<script>
    let config = {
        region: 'xxx',
        pool: 'xxx',
        bucket: 'xxx'
    }
    
    AWS.config.region = config.region;
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
        IdentityPoolId: config.pool,
    });
    
    var s3 = new AWS.S3({
        apiVersion: '2006-03-01',
        params: {Bucket: config.bucket},
    });
    
    start_upload = function (event) {
        $("#status").text("Uploading, please wait...");
    
        let file = $("#file").prop('files')[0];
        if (file === null || file === undefined) {
            alert("You must choose a file before submitting.");
            $("#status").text("");
            return false;
        }
    
        let workerId = turkGetParam('workerId');
        let fileKey = '${food_name}' + '/' + workerId + '-' + file.name;
    
        upload_to_s3(file, fileKey);
        
        return false;
    };
  
    upload_to_s3 = (file, fileKey) => {
        const params = {
            Key: fileKey,
            Body: file,
            ContentType: file.type,
            ACL: 'bucket-owner-full-control'
        };
    
        let promise = s3.upload(params).promise();
        promise.then( (data) => {
            console.log("Upload completed");
            $("#status").text("Success.");
            
            const form = document.getElementById('mturk_form');
            form.submit();
        }, (err) => {
            console.log("Upload failed!!!", err);
            alert("Failed to upload, please try again. If the problem persists, contact the Requester.");
            $("#status").text("");
        } );
    }
  
    // Validate and upload file on submit
    window.onload = function() {document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'return start_upload()'); }
</script>
```